# Is thread returned to threadpool of executor service if future task throws exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have simple use case of ThreadPoolExecutor. I want to ensure during the thread execution if there is any kind of run time exception, Will threads be returned back to the pool or not. How to verify ?

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
pool.submit(new MyThread())
boolean jobExecutionStatus =true 
try{
       for (Future<Boolean> future : futureArrayList){
                if (jobExecutionStatus){
                    jobExecutionStatus = future.get();
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e){
            jobExecutionStatus = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, if an `Exception` is thrown a new `Thread` will be created (only if necessary).

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)):

> **If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution** prior to
>   shutdown, **a new one will take its place if needed** to execute
>   subsequent tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your swift response.